# Have I obtained the correct transfer functions for the following RCL circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog, transfer-function

Have I obtained the correct transfer functions for the following RCL circuit?
Please note that my Maths is a little rusty!

[image: RCL Circuit 1]

$$\dfrac{Eo(s)}{Ei(s)}=\dfrac{1}{(R_1C_1L_1)s^2+(R_1R_2C_1)s+R_1} \tag{1}$$

Defining $$Z_1 = R_1 $$

Defining the series impendance between \$R_2\$ and \$C_1\$

$$Z_s=\dfrac{1}{sC_1} + R_2 = \dfrac{1+sR_2C_1}{sC_1} $$

Defining the parallel impendance between \$R_2\$, \$C_1\$  and \$L1\$

$$Z_p = \dfrac{Z_sZ_L1}{Z_s+Z_L1}=\dfrac{\dfrac{1+sR_2C_1}{sC_1}sL_1}{\dfrac{1+sR_2C_1}{sC_1}+sL_1} =\dfrac{\dfrac{s^2R_2C_1L_1+sL_1}{sC_1}}{\dfrac{1+sR_2C_1}{sC_1}+sL_1}$$

Multiplying numerator and deniminator through by sC

$$Z_p=Z_2=\dfrac{s^2R_2C_1L_1+sL_1}{s^2C_1L_1+sR_2C_1+1} \tag{2}$$

Therefore, we have that

$$\dfrac{Eo(s)}{Ei(s)}=\dfrac{Z_2}{Z_1+Z_2}= \dfrac{\dfrac{s^2R_2C_1L_1+sL_1}{s^2C_1L_1+sR2C+1}}{{R1}+\dfrac{s^2R_2C_1L_1+sL}{s^2C_1L_1+sR2C+1}}$$

Simplifying

$$\dfrac{Eo(s)}{Ei(s)}=\dfrac{s^2R_2C_1L_1+sL_1}{{R_1(s^2C_1L_1+sR_2C_1+1)}+{s^2R_2C_1L_1+sL}}\tag{3}$$

The $$ s^2R_2CL+sL $$ terms cancels out with the one in the denominator and we're left with the following

$$\dfrac{Eo(s)}{Ei(s)}=\dfrac{1}{(R_1C_1L_1)s^2+(R_1R_2C_1)s+R_1} \tag{4}$$

Comment: In your first circuit, imagine what happens at \$\omega=0\$ and at \$\omega=\infty\$. What does the circuit do? What does your transfer function do?

Comment: Where are the outputs?

Comment: Since you're showing images made with LTspice, why not verify them yourself? Add a VCVS (`F2` > `e`) and change its value to be `Laplace=`, then use the transfer functions you derived. E.g. for your 1st t.f. it should be: `Laplace=1/(s*2*R1*C*L+s*R1*R2*C+R1)`, where `R1, R2, L, C` are defined with `.param` statements (which can be assigned to the RLC elements with `{R1}`, `{L}`, etc). Don't forget the source with `AC 1`.

Comment: You have made some mistakes, but we don't hand out homework solutions here so you need to show us all of your work. Then, as a specific question.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I have used LTspice to verify whether the TFs are right in terms of having a stable or unstable behaviour! However, is your suggestion that I can use the TFs directly within LTspice? If so, I will give that a try!

Comment: @jonk at this point, I'm just trying to gauge whether I understand the method for determining transfer functions correctly and was just looking for feedback on which one, if any, I may have made a mistake on.

Comment: @Chu the outputs are all to the right extremity!

Comment: (1) cannot be correct because the DC gain of the circuit is zero, and your TF gives \$\frac{1}{R_1}\$

Comment: @Chu I've just re-edited my question to focus on (1) and I still get the same result. Can you pls point me to where I am going wrong in my calculation?

Comment: Basic algebra. Your error is ... 'the $$ s^2R2CL+sL $$ terms cancel out'. They don't!

Comment: @Chu Thanks, I've just realised that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I won't show what you have wrong, since you're saying that [you're practising](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/555695/have-i-obtained-the-correct-transfer-functions-for-the-following-rcl-circuits?noredirect=1#comment1450736_555695), but it doesn't make much sense to not use LTspice to verify yourself as opposed to just using it as a screenshot provider. As I said in the comments, this is how you could do it (BTW, there was a typo I missed in the `Laplace` expression):

[image: test]

Note that `Laplace` expressions can use `^` as exponentiation, but only here, otherwise the double asterisk `**` is used. Two minor "gotcha"s:

- The source is a voltage source so as long as it doesn't have any resistance in the way (be it external, like `R1`, or internal, like `Rser`), the input voltage will be unaffected therefore it can be reused for the `E1`.
- Inductors and capacitors have some default parasitics specified, L has 1 mΩ series resistance, and C a `1/Gmin` parallel resistance, so depending on the amount of bandwidth you're simulating, you may see some effects. To be sure there are none, <kbd>RClick</kbd> on the L or C and set all the parasitics to zero.

---

I find it difficult to follow your math, so here's how it should go, using your approach (there are many ways to do it):

$$\begin{align}
Z_c&=\dfrac{1}{sC}+R_2 \\
&=\dfrac{sR_2C+1}{sC} \tag{1} \\
Z_o&=\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{1}{sL}+\dfrac{sC}{sR_2C+1}} \\
&=\dfrac{s^2R_2LC+sL}{s^2LC+sR_2C+1} \tag{2} \\
H(s)&=\dfrac{Z_o}{Z_o+R_1}=\dfrac{\mathrm{Num}\Bigl(H(s)\Bigr)}{\mathrm{Den}\Bigl(H(s)\Bigr)} \tag{3} \\
\mathrm{Num}\Bigl(H(s)\Bigr)&=\dfrac{s^2R_2LC+sL}{s^2LC+sR_2C+1} \tag{4} \\
\mathrm{Den}\Bigl(H(s)\Bigr)&=\dfrac{s^2R_2LC+sL}{s^2LC+sR_2C+1}+R_1 \\
&=\dfrac{s^2LC(R_1+R_2)+s(R_1R_2C+L)+R_1}{s^2LC+sR_2C+1} \tag{5} \\
\Rightarrow H(s)&=\dfrac{s^2R_2LC+sL}{s^2LC(R_1+R_2)+s(R_1R_2C+L)+R_1} \tag{6}
\end{align}$$

I have skipped basic math steps, I'm sure you can follow the thread. And this is the test:

[image: test2]

The red trace has a slightly different phase than the `Laplace` expression and that's because of the 2nd point mentioned above: the default 1 mΩ series resistor for the inductance (left on purpose).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. I can see that my TF doesn't have the same behaviour as the circuit. I'll try the TF as it is before I simplified it to see what its response is! Btw, where do I locate the voltage source with the multiple terminals and how d I invoke the Laplace function?

Comment: @aLoHa It seems to me it would be far more productive for you to follow a tutorial on how to use LTspice, but I would actually start with the manual. It's terse, spartan, laconic, but it has the information you need. For this case I'll only repeat what I wrote in the comments: `F2` > `e` is the VCVS, and `RClick` on its value (the `E`, **not** `E1` -- that's the reference designator) and then simply type or copy-paste the expression. Again, I highly recommend starting with the manual, it will save you a lot of cusses and unnecessary sweat.

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance. It is very much appreciated. I see now that my mistake was in cancelling out the "s^2R2CL + sL" from top and bottom, which is not mathematically correct in itself, instead of expanding and then simplying! Can, I just say that you give great advice? I don't always take the time to take them in on my 1st read. But, I will from now on.

Comment: Now that you say that I can see the error in your last step. I found it difficult to follow the notations because you haven't used indices, so it looks monotonous to my eyes. Well, as long as you realized where the error is, all's well!

Comment: Any chance of a vote for my question? :)

Comment: I already did that (and that's not something you ask for, anyway).

Comment: Yes, I know and I previously acknowledged you doing so. But, for some strange reason, I still have zero votes for my question. But, I won’t ask again.

Comment: @aLoHa Then it means somebody downvoted. You can verify this in your account page.